# Can a record constant be a record of records in Delphi 6?

Tags: delphi, syntax

I can define record constants like this:

```
const
  dialoghdr: DLGTEMPLATE =
    (style: 1; dwExtendedStyle: 2; cdit: 3; x: 4; y: 5; cx: 6; cy: 7);
  dialogitem: DLGITEMTEMPLATE =
    (style: 8; dwExtendedStyle: 9; x: 10; y: 11; cx: 12; cy: 13; id: 14);
```

and I can define a record of records like this:

```
type
  template = packed record
    header: DLGTEMPLATE;
    item: DLGITEMTEMPLATE;
    end;
```

and although the compiler will accept this:

```
const mytemplate: template = (); // compiles!
```

is there a way to actually put constants in the ()?  Something like

```
const mytemplate: template = 
    (header.style: 1; header.dwExtendedStyle: 2; header.cdit: 3...,
     item.style: 8; item.dwExtendedStyle: 9; item.x: 10...);
```

or

```
const mytemplate: template = 
    ((style: 1; dwExtendedStyle: 2; cdit: 3; x: 4; y: 5; cx: 6; cy: 7),
    (style: 8; dwExtendedStyle: 9; x: 10; y: 11; cx: 12; cy: 13; id: 14));
```

Can a record constant be a record of records, or not?  I'm using Delphi 6.  (I realize a workaround would be to redefine template as only a single-level record of fields.)

Comment: You can learn how to do this from the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Record_Constants

Comment: That's the same description as the Delphi 6 documentation.  It only implies, but does not actually document, the proper syntax for a record of records.

Comment: Sure it does. You just have to read the documentation recursively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is very possible, and you almost know how to do it:

```
const mytemplate: template =
  (header: (style: 1; dwExtendedStyle: 2; cdit: 3; x: 4; y: 5; cx: 6; cy: 7);
   item: (style: 8; dwExtendedStyle: 9; x: 10; y: 11; cx: 12; cy: 13; id: 14));
```

You simply follow the same pattern at each 'level'.